# Swift - How to implement "like post"

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am implementing a Question & Answer program using Swift with Firebase. I want users to be able to like the answers of questions. My database structure for handling likes is:

```
answerLikes
   answerID 
      userID : true
answers
   ...
posts
   ...
users
   ...
```

I tried to implement my program according to this data structure. You can see the code in my TableViewController:

```
@IBAction func likeButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        ref = Database.database().reference()

        print(indexPath.row)

        ref.child("answerLikes").child(answers[indexPath.row].id).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
            (snapshot) in

            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

            if value?[Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid] == nil {
                sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "filledHeart.png"), for: .normal)
                self.ref.child("answerLikes").child(self.answers[indexPath.row].id).updateChildValues([(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)! : true])
            } else {
                sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "emptyHeart.png"), for: .normal)
                self.ref.child("answerLikes").child(self.answers[indexPath.row].id).removeValue()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

My problem is that in this function definition, I cannot know that "the tapped like button is in which cell?". We handle this issue in the table view function by using indexPath. So I tried to use it in this code too, however, my code works only if the user clicks the cell and then clicks the like button.

Can anyone help me with this please? I am really having serious problem with this "Like Post" feature. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First way**

If you are using a custom cell you can use a protocol:

```
protocol CustomCellDelegate: class {
    func likeButtonClicked(cell: YourCell)
}

class YourCell: UITableViewCell {
    weak var delegate: CustomCellDelegate?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    @IBAction func likeButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject){
        delegate?.likeButtonClicked(self)
    }
}
```

Then add the delegate to your ViewController and in cellForRowAtIndexPath set it for your cell:

```
cell.delegate = self
```

And finally you can use it in this way:

```
func likeButtonClicked(cell: YourCell) {
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {
        //....
    }
}
```

**Second way**

You can get the index with your button position:

```
@IBAction func likeButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    var buttonPosition = sender.convertPoint(.zero, to: self.tableView)
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition) {
        //.....
    }
}
```

**Third way**

In cellForRowAtIndexPath you can use your button tag:

```
likeButton.tag = indexPath.row
```

And then:

```
@IBAction func likeButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let cellRow = sender.tag
    //...
}
```

Comment: You made my day, I thank you so much. Great guidance!

Comment: It's me again, sorry to bother you but, can you help me with counting the number of likes? I am having trouble with it. I can count the number of likes with "snapshot.childrenCount()", but I want the page to update likes as the user taps the like button. I think I should handle that in likeButtonClicked function, but couldn't find a way to do it.

Comment: Hi ;) if you get the new likes count value after the update you can set it as your button title and reload the row using its index path in likeButtonClicked function.